# A regex to match excel function name / replace excel function name to another function name

Tags: c#, regex

I face the following problem....
I have for example one of those strings:

```
string formula1 = "=SUMME(A1:A6)"
string formula2 = "=RUNDEN(SUMME(A6);1)"
string formula3 = "=AUFRUNDEN(ABS(RUNDEN(SUMME(A1:A6);2));2)"
string formula4 = "=AUFRUNDEN(RUNDEN(ABS(RUNDEN(SUMME(A1:A6);2));2);2)"
```

these are Excel formulas in German language
but I really need the function names to be replaced to function names in English language

I have thought about creating a dictionary, consisting of German function names(Keys)and English function names(Values)

would it be appropriate to find the German function names via regex in order to replace them with English terms later on?

unfortunately my regex knowledge is not really good and it is hard for me to create a regex that would match this pattern. Or would you solve it differently?

hope that is so far understandable. Thx for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
(?<name>[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\s*\(
```

pattern; so function

1. Must *start* from `A..Z` or `a..z`
2. Can *contain* `A..Z` or `a..z` or `0..9` charactes
3. Must *end* with zero or more *whitespaces* and `(`

**Code:**

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> subs = 
  new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    //TODO: add {Deutsch, English}, pairs here
    { "RUNDEN",    "ROUND" },
    { "ABS",       "ABS" },
    { "SUMME",     "SUM" },
    { "AUFRUNDEN", "ROUNDUP"},
};

private static string ConvertExcel(string formula) {
  return Regex.Replace(
     formula,
    @"(?<name>[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\s*\(",
     m => subs.TryGetValue(m.Groups["name"].Value, out var newValue)
       ? newValue + "("
       : m.Value); // do nothing, if translation is not found
}
```

**Demo:**

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "=SUMME(A1:A6)",
  "=RUNDEN(SUMME(A6);1)",
  "=AUFRUNDEN(ABS(RUNDEN(SUMME(A1:A6);2));2)",
  "=AUFRUNDEN(RUNDEN(ABS(RUNDEN(SUMME(A1:A6);2));2);2)",
};

var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,-52} <=> {ConvertExcel(test)}"));

Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
=SUMME(A1:A6)                                        <=> =SUM(A1:A6)
=RUNDEN(SUMME(A6);1)                                 <=> =ROUND(SUM(A6);1)
=AUFRUNDEN(ABS(RUNDEN(SUMME(A1:A6);2));2)            <=> =ROUNDUP(ABS(ROUND(SUM(A1:A6);2));2)
=AUFRUNDEN(RUNDEN(ABS(RUNDEN(SUMME(A1:A6);2));2);2)  <=> =ROUNDUP(ROUND(ABS(ROUND(SUM(A1:A6);2));2);2)
```